# How to match against two different criteria in LINQ Where?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a Data Table as below:

| ID | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 10 |
| 2 | 1 | 10 |
| 3 | 1 | 10 |
| 4 | 1 | 20 |
| 5 | 2 | 20 |
| 6 | 2 | 20 |

How do I match rows where Column B has a given value (1 for instance) AND Column C has a given value (10 for instance) using LINQ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take a few minutes to read the documentation on how to ask a good question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please read the [how-to-ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to improve your question and help us to understand your problem. One way: `var count = YOURDATATABLE.AsEnumerable().Where(row=> row.Field<int>("B") == 1 && row.Field<int>("C") == 10).Count();`

Answer (score 1):

You can use multiple conditions inside your `.Where()` call, as you would inside an `if()` statement. You do this using the `&&` operator.

```
int expectedB = 1;
int expectedC = 10;

int result = collection.Where(_ => _.B == expectedB && _.C == expectedC).Count()
```

or via query syntax:

```
int result = (from row in collection
where row.B == expectedB && row.C == expectedC
select ___).Count()
```

Comment: I'm not sure why this was voted down. It is the correct answer. My best guess is that it's a duplicate question though.

Comment: I think it was downvoted because it was a code only answer until I edited it @NicholaiRen

Comment: Have you tested this against a `DataTable`, what's the outcome?

Comment: `_` is a special character that provides the discard functionality. Even though it's also a valid variable name I would recommend not to use it as such.

Comment: @Persistence I would say it's because the solution doesn't work as is.

Comment: thank you @zaggler, I haven't seen an ADO.NET tag, so missed the fact that the question is related to `DataTable` specifically.

Comment: @Sergey you're welcome, it's ok. You could do something along the lines of `var result = dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Where(_ => _.Field<int>("B") == expectedB && _.Field<int>("C") == expectedC).Count();`

Comment: or just `dt.AsEnumerable.Count(_ => _.Field<int>("B") == expectedB && _.Field<int>("C") == expected)`, indeed